# Can you (theoretically) reverse bias a BJT?

Tags: bjt, manufacturing-process

My understanding of how a BJT(bipolar transistor) works looks like this:
[image: A NPN transistor breakdown]

From https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-2/bipolar-junction-transistors/
Picture link: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/npn-junction-bipolar-transistor-with-reverse-biased-collector-base.png

However, I don't see any specific reason why a transistor should be biased in one direction. If an  NPN is just pieces of doped silicon symmetrically sandwiched together, why should it be specifically biased to conduct electricity in one direction?

Is there something to do with the manufacturing process that adds an additional diode, for example to a transistor to make current only flow in one direction(without breaking down?)?
Or is my understanding of a transistor just flawed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can exchange emitter and collector, but the transistor won't work as well.

Generally the emitter is doped much higher than the base, and base is doped higher than the collector. This improves gain (hFE or beta) because injection efficiency (the ratio of emitter carriers injected into the base to base carriers injected into the emitter) is higher.

Also, a rich B-E junction has a low breakdown voltage -- the emitter is usually doped as heavy as is possible, and this means the B-E junction breakdown voltage is 6-10 V. Most discrete transistors have collector-base (BVCBO) breakdown voltages over 40 V, and higher V device are available.

The lightly-doped collector may have some excessive series resistance which is not a problem in normal bias, but would affect the device performance in reverse bias.

Comment: I think the emitters are usually physically smaller than the collectors, too.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't matter much. Overall, capacitance of the B-E junction is more than that of the C-B because the doping is orders of magnitude heavier and that swamps any area differences.

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary BJTs (for example, 2N3906 or 2N4401) will work in reverse (swap E and C).

However they will not be optimal in most regards due to the doping profiles. The "collector base" breakdown will be less than 10V generally and the current gain may be 5 or 10 rather than 200 or 300.

On the other hand, they have a large breakdown from base to the faux emitter and the saturation voltage is a bit less.

There have been symmetrical transistors made which were pretty similar one way or the other, but they've pretty much died out with the emergence of inexpensive CMOS analog switches. You can still find some such as [2SC2878](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/212673/TOSHIBA/2SC2878.html) which are fairly symmetrical (may not be in current production).